# How to use select All option for radio button?

Tags: angularjs

Here I have created a record using some radio button. And what I need is when I select the selectAll radio button the selected records should appear in the same page.

When I unselect any radio button in a record the black mark in selectAll checkbox should not appear in the checkbox the same example which we use in our g-mail where gmail use the check box and I'm trying to do it with radio button.

-----here is my index.html-------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.0-beta.6" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.6/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">

   <span>Table One</span>

<div ng-controller="peopleCtrl">
    <label>
            <input type="radio" 
                   ng-model="allChecked" 
            ng-click="checkAll()" /> Select All
        </label>

      <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr> 
           <th>check</th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>        
                    </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">




              <td>
                    <input type="radio"  ng-model="person.check" ng-click="changeCheckAll()" /> 
              </td>      
                           <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
                           <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                           <td>{{ person.age }}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <span>Table Two</span>
    <table width="400" border="1">
       <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th> 
            </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter: {check:true}">
            <td>{{person.id}}</td>
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

And my script page

```
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('peopleCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.people = ([{
    id: 1,
    name: "Anil",
    age: 21
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Niladri",
    age: 20
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Venkat",
    age: 22
  }]);




 $scope.checkAll = function() {
        for(var i=0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {
            $scope.people[i].check = $scope.allChecked;
        }
    };


    $scope.changeCheckAll = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {

            if (!$scope.people[i].check) {
                $scope.allChecked = false;
                return false;
            }
        }


        $scope.allChecked = true;
    };
});
```

And my plnkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/RKAdEZYvsJu5wbhIs41A?p=preview

Comment: please try using spell check, also ... wall of code

Comment: Please use a checkbox. radio buttons are meant to select a single option in a group of options

Comment: i have already  used this using checkbox and it worked perfectly  but my  task  is to  be done by  using radio button....

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="peopleCtrl">
    <label>
            <input type="checkbox" 
                   ng-model="allChecked" 
            ng-click="checkAll()" /> Select All
        </label>

      <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr> 
           <th>check</th>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>        
                    </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">




              <td>
                    <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="person.check" ng-click="changeCheckAll()" /> 
              </td>      
                           <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
                           <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                           <td>{{ person.age }}</td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

radio button is intended to be used when you want to give the user an option to select just one option in a set of options. You are using the radio button wrongly. Checkbox works perfectly here! http://plnkr.co/edit/udgGcsMTubxf4yZapm10?p=preview

Comment: K can i use the radio button to  bind the table of document which  displays me in the table two  instead of using the select all  option

Comment: I did not get you. Do you want to use radio buttons in table which has checkboxes now?

Comment: Yes that  was my  plan but  as u  said that  was not possible ,so  can  i  bind only  the particular  record which  will display  in the table two

Comment: That's what its currently doing too isn't it? You need to use checkboxes in that table, coz you want to give the option to select multiple records